# Make Row Lock in process insert with multiple user

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

I'm having an issue when inserting data with multiple user in my project.

I am using Hibernate 3.6.9 and SQL Server 2008.

When a user try to insert data in one table, it locks the table transaction. And 
if another user try to insert data with same table simultaneously, this process must wait for the previous transaction to remove the lock, which takes time.

I want to set the lock on the particular row  only and not on the whole table.

Any idea how I can do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ROWLOCK for your INSERT as described here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/control-sql-server-locking-with-hints/. However, you may need to look deeper into Hibernate's documentation to see if this is supported by its dialect for SQL Server or there is any special API for the same purpose.

Hope this helps.